# Need to classify wkbs to left and right of a median wkb so that I can add directionality to it

Tags: geometry, maps, jts

I have three parallel wkbs. I have the middle one. I want to classify the other two so that I can give direction based on a right driven country or a left driven country. How do I classify it.

Middle wkb: 010200000008000000FE59982ABD3B28400E2C47C840D24B40

Other wkbs:
010200000002000000843EA253A13B284025C4019942D24B40
0102000000140000005776C1E09A3B28400A05B6943DD24B40